# Может кто помочь с решением задачи ? Язык JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать функцию, которая проверяет можно ли из первой строки получить вторую, поменяв в ней символы местами. Все символы из исходной строки должны быть использованы ровно один раз, кроме пробелов, которые можно добавлять и удалять.

Comment: Можно в лоб пробегаться по строке и считать количество вхождений символов, также пробегаться по второй строке и сравнивать результаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот прикольный вариант:

```js
function check(s1, s2) {
  return s1.match(/\S|$/g).sort().join() === s2.match(/\S|$/g).sort().join()
}

console.log(check("clockwise", "owe clicks"))
console.log(check("clockwise", "clockwork"))    
console.log(check("", " "))
console.log(check("aa", "a"))
```

Comment: Обидно. Написал почти такой же ответ, но, как оказалось, не нажал кнопку "отправить ответ". А теперь уже нет смысла. :)

Comment: Хм, но если будет не пробел, а, скажем, табуляция, то всё ещё будет равенство, хотя исключён только он :)

Comment: @Other, исключены все пробельные символы. И ещё небольшой финт для пустой строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Но, по условию, исключать можно только пробелы, а добавление табов - это уже как полноценный символ вроде `a`, поэтому и сравнивать их количество нужно.

Comment: @Other, обычно под пробелами понимают любые пробельные символы. Если нужны именно пробелы, то `[^ ]`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Количество учитывается?

Comment: @Other, какое ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Количественное.

Comment: @Other, я не понимаю вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Забей тогда :)

Answer (score 1):

На закуску - понять как работает.

```js
let check = (o, t) => {
  t = t.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').split('');
  return o.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').split('').filter(p => !t.includes(p)).length === 0;
}

console.info(check('clockwise', 'owe clicks'));
console.info(check('clockwise', 'clockwork'));
```

Comment: `t.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '')` удалит только первый пробел.

Comment: @Yaant, там через регулярку сделано.

Comment: Неверно: `check('aa', 'a')`

Comment: @Other вижу. Тут какая-то мистика. Я код в комментарий копировал копипастом, но никаких признаков редактирования ответа не вижу. :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, действительно так, но мы ведь не хотим чтобы автор просто взял и отнёс работу преподу, а сам подумал и нашёл огрехи?

Comment: @Yaant, Just because it's magic!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте продебажить следующий код. Удачи.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CheckStrings('clockwise', 'owe clicks');
CheckStrings('clockwise', 'clockwork');
function CheckStrings (str1, str2) {
    debugger;
    var chars1 = str1.split('');
    var chars2 = str2.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < chars2.length; i++) {
        if (chars1.indexOf(chars2[i]) == -1 && chars2[i] != ' ') {
            console.log('false');
            return false;
        }
    }
    console.log('true');
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !